# Prove this integration by parts formula

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have been struggling on this problem :

> We work in $([0,\infty[,B(\mathbb{R}),\nu_1)$.  Let $f,g\in \mathcal{L^1}$, and
> \begin{align}
> F(x)&=\int_0^{x}f(t)\,dt\\
> G(x)&=\int_0^{x}g(t)\,dt
> \end{align}
> Show:
> $$\int_0^{\infty}F(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx\int_0^{\infty}g(x)\,dx-\int_0^{\infty}f(x)G(x)\,dx$$

The first question is about showing that $F,G$ are bounded (that's because $f,g\in\mathcal{L^1}$), and that they are continuous (by using the theorem about continuity of integrals with parameters with $f*1_{[0,x]}$ as function of $x$ and $t$).

But when it comes to proving the equation, I really am stuck. I've tried a couple of things, but none that's worth sharing. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof 1 ( Using the notion of absolute continuity and its consequences)**

Fix some $t>0$. Since, $f,g$ are integrable, it follows that $F,G$ are absolutely continuous on the closed and bounded interval $[0,t]$. This means, that $F,G$ are differentiable everywhere on $[0,t]$ and $F'(x)=f(x),\,G'(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere. Now, $F\cdot G$ is also absolutely continuous on $[0,t]$ hence it is differentiable almost everywhere and
$$\tag{1} [F(x)\cdot G(x)]'=f(x)G(x)+g(x)F(x)$$
almost everywhere. Also, by the absolute continuity of $F\cdot G$ we also have
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}[F(x)\cdot G(x)]'&=F(t)\cdot G(t)-F(0)\cdot G(0)\\
&=\biggl(\int_0^tf(x)\,dx\biggr)\cdot \biggl(\int_0^tg(x)\,dx\biggr)\tag{2}
\end{align}
Integrating $(1)$ and using $(2)$ we obtain
$$\int_0^t F(x)g(x)\,dx=\biggl(\int_0^tf(x)\,dx\biggr)\cdot \biggl(\int_0^tg(x)\,dx\biggr)-\int_0^tf(x)G(x)\,dx\tag{3}$$
Now, let $s_t(x)=F(x)g(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,t]}$. Then, $s_t(x)\to F(x)g(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}$ as $t\to \infty$. Also,
$$|s_t(x)|\leq M|g(x)|\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}$$
where $M$ is the bound of $F(x)$. Since $g$ is integrable it follows by the dominated convergence theorem that
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^tF(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty F(x)g(x)\,dx
$$
Similarly, $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_0^tf(x)G(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^\infty f(x)G(x)\,dx$ and $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx,\ \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^t g(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$$
So, take $t\to \infty$ in $(3)$ to conclude
$$\int_{0}^\infty F(x)g(x)\,dx=\biggl(\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx\biggr)\cdot \biggl(\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx\biggr)-\int_0^\infty f(x)G(x)\,dx$$

**Proof 2 (Approach with indicator functions and approximation arguments)**

I think you can prove $(2)$ (in **Proof 1**) for indicator functions, say $f=\mathbb{1}_A,\,g=\mathbb{1}_B$ with $\mu(A)<\infty,\,\mu(B)<\infty$ and then use the classic method by approximating general measurable functions $f,\,g\in L^1$ with simple functions and use the convergence theorems (Monotone for positive $f,g$, dominated for general $f,g$). Although, i find this approach quite ugly but is the only think i could think off. So suppose $f=\mathbb{1}_A,\,g=\mathbb{1}_B$ with $\mu(A),\mu(B)<\infty$. Then, fix $t>0$ and observe that
$$F(x)=\mu\bigl(A\cap[0,x]\bigr),\, G(x)=\mu\bigl(B\cap [0,x]\bigr)$$
for every $0\leq x\leq t$. Write,
\begin{align}
\int_0^t F(x)g(x)\,dx&=\int_0^t\mu\bigl(A\cap [0,x]\bigr)g(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^t\bigg(\mu\bigl(A\cap [0,t]\bigr)-\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)\biggr)\cdot g(x)\,dx\\
&=\mu\bigl(A\cap [0,t]\bigr)\int_0^t g(x)\,dx-\int_0^t\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)g(x)\,dx\\
&=\biggl(\int_0^t f(x)\,dx\biggr)\cdot \biggl(\int_0^t g(x)\,dx\biggr)-\int_0^t\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)g(x)\,dx
\end{align}
And we claim that
$$\tag{4} \int_0^t\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^t G(x)f(x)\,dx$$
Writing $\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)$ as $\int_x^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\,dy$ and using Tonelli's theorem to interchange the order of integration we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^t\mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)g(x)&=\int_0^t\biggl(\int_x^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\,dy\biggr)g(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^t\biggl(\int_x^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\,dy\biggr)\cdot \mathbb{1}_B(x)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^t\biggl(\int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{A\cap [x,t]}(y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_B(x)\biggr)dy\,dx\\
&=\int_0^t\biggl(\int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{A\cap [x,t]}(y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_B(x)\biggr)dx\,dy \tag{5}
\end{align}
Now, fix $0\leq y\leq t$ and observe that
$$\tag{6}\mathbb{1}_B(x)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{A\cap [x,t]}(y)=\mathbb{1}_A(y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{B\cap [0,y]}(x)$$
for every $0\leq x\leq t$. Using $(6)$ in $(5)$ we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \mu\bigl(A\cap [x,t]\bigr)\cdot \mathbb{1}_B(x)&=\int_0^t\biggl(\int_0^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{B\cap[0,y]}(x)\,dx\biggr)\,dy\\
&=\int_0^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\biggl(\mathbb{1}_{B\cap [0,y]}(x)\,dx\biggr)\,dy\\
&=\int_0^t \mathbb{1}_A(y)\cdot \mu\bigl(B\cap [0,y]\bigr)\,dy\\
&=\int_0^t f(y)\cdot G(y)\,dy
\end{align}
and $(4)$ is proven! (phew!)

Ps: I didnt check the details for the approximation arguments for general $f,g$ i expect that it can work.

Comment: Hi ,thank your for our answer. At this point in our course, we haven't really introduced the notion of absolute continuity, what theorems can I use to get to (2) without using absolute continuity ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user310148 i edited the answer above and i added a different approach w/o using the absolute continuity, only Tonelli's theorem (or Fubini) .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awesome